# Should I model separate objects for game assets?

Tags: modeling, objects, workflow, geometry

I am still new to blender, and making art for a game. When it comes to what is consider "performant", is it better to do it like I've done in the image here, or should each fence post be a separate object, so that I don't have to subdivide the main model so many times?

What is considered the "correct" way of doing something like this?

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48913/should-i-make-my-model-into-1-whole-or-multiple-parts/48925#48925 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49988/storing-many-instances-efficiently/49995#49995

Comment: Multiple objects means there are multiple objects in the outliner. It doesn't count if your mesh has multiple loose geometry, it will be one object and won't decrease the performance. So don't subdivide unnecessarily.